# "None is not a generator" in Python - El Farol algorithm

Tags: python, class, generator, netlogo

I'm writing El Farol model from Netlogo in Python. However, I keep receiving this error and I have no idea how to move on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-444-99b2c0f618f2>", line 3, in <module>
    village.run()
  File "<ipython-input-441-cb8708c7230d>", line 143, in run
    Agent(self)
  File "<ipython-input-441-cb8708c7230d>", line 22, in __init__
    self.village.env.process(self.move())
  File "C:\Users\jkowalczyk002\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpy\events.py", line 272, in __init__
    raise ValueError('%s is not a generator.' % generator)
ValueError: None is not a generator.
```

Messages indicate that there is something wrong with move() function, but to me it looks fine:

```
def move(self):
    new_loc = self.gen_loc()
    del self.village.occupied[self.loc]
    self.loc = new_loc
    self.village.data[self.loc] = 1
```

It should go from `move` -> `gen_loc` -> `najlepsza` (English - best) -> `do_baru` (E - to bar), but it gets `None`.

Whole code:

```
import simpy
import random
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors
from gridplot import GridPlot

white_green = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["green","white"])
plt.register_cmap(cmap=white_green)

class Agent:
    def __init__(self,village):
        self.village = village
        self.color = 1
        self.loc = self.gen_loc()
        self.village.env.process(self.move())

    def gen_loc(self):
        if self.najlepsza()<self.village.threshold:
            self.loc = (random.randrange(math.floor(self.village.village_dim/2)+1,self.village.village_dim),
                        random.randrange(math.floor(self.village.village_dim/2)+1,self.village.village_dim))
            if self.loc not in self.village.occupied:
                self.village.occupied[self.loc] = self
        elif random.random()>0.33:
            self.loc =(random.randrange(0,math.floor(self.village.village_dim/2)-1,
                       random.randrange(0,self.village.village_dim)))
            if self.loc not in self.village.occupied:
                self.village.occupied[self.loc] = self
        else:
            self.loc =(random.randrange(math.floor(self.village.village_dim/2),self.village.village_dim),
            random.randrange(0,math.floor(self.village.village_dim/2)-1))
            if self.loc not in self.village.occupied:
                self.village.occupied[self.loc] = self

    def najlepsza(self):
        if self.village.env.now<2:
                strategia=[]
                for j in range(village.liczbastr):
                    for i in range(village.memorysize):
                        strategia.append(random.random())
                sumy=[]
                for j in range(village.liczbastr):
                    sumy.append(sum(strategia[i+village.memorysize*j] for i in range(village.memorysize)))
                strategia1=[]
                for j in range(village.liczbastr):
                    for i in range(village.memorysize):
                        strategia1.append(strategia[i+j*village.memorysize]/sumy[j])
                listypre=[strategia1[i:i+village.memorysize] for i in range(0, village.memorysize*village.liczbastr, village.memorysize)]
                zestaw1=np.array(listypre)
        historia1=village.historia
        wynikstrat=[]
        for j in range(village.liczbastr):
            for k in range(village.memorysize):
                wynikstrat.append(sum(historia1[-i-2-k]*zestaw1[j,-i-1] for i in range(village.memorysize)))
        listypre=[]
        listypre=[wynikstrat[i:i+village.memorysize] for i in range(0, village.memorysize*village.liczbastr, village.memorysize)]
        tabela1=np.array(listypre)+10
        wynik=village.memorysize*100
        naj=village.liczbastr
        pred=0
        for j in range(village.liczbastr):
            if (sum(abs(tabela1[j,i]-historia1[-i-1]) for i in range(village.memorysize)))<wynik:
                wynik=sum(abs(tabela1[j,i]-historia1[-i-1]) for i in range(village.memorysize))
                naj=j
        pred=sum(historia1[-1-i]*zestaw1[naj,-i-1] for i in range(village.memorysize))
        return(pred)

    def do_baru(self):
        return(self.najlepsza() <= self.village.threshold)

    def move(self):
        new_loc = self.gen_loc()
        del self.village.occupied[self.loc]
        self.loc = new_loc
        self.village.data[self.loc] = 1

class Village:
    def __init__(self, env, village_dim, memorysize, liczbastr,threshold):
        self.village_dim = village_dim
        self.memorysize = memorysize
        self.liczbastr = liczbastr
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.env=env
        self.historia=self.historialos()

    def historialos(self):
        if self.env.now<2:
            historia=[]
            for i in range(2*self.memorysize):
                historia.append(random.randint(0,100))
        return(historia)

    def histupdate(self):
        for i in range(2*self.memorysize):
            self.historia[i-1]=self.historia[i]
        self.historia[2*self.memorysize-1]=self.attendance()
        return(self.historia)

    def attendance(self):
        attend=0
        for v in self.occupied.values():
            if v.do_baru():
                attend = attend+1

    def plot(self, start):
        self.data = np.zeros((self.village_dim, self.village_dim))
        for agent in self.occupied:
            self.data[agent] = self.occupied[agent].color
        self.gp = GridPlot(self.data, ["white", "green"])

    def run(self):
        self.occupied = dict()
        agent_count = 100
        print(self.historia)
        for i in range(agent_count):
            Agent(self)
        self.env.process(self.plot())
        self.histupdate()

env = simpy.Environment()
village = Village(env, 50,10,5,50)
village.run()
```

Comment: It's considered a very bad habit to add new attributes to class instances outside the `__init__` method, yet you do it. All attributes should be created at the initialisation step. Set them to `None` if you don't have a proper value, but place them where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.core.html#simpy.core.Environment.process, the `process` method expects a generator argument, but you are not yielding anything from the `move` method, thus the error you are getting.